# UNIX Replacing a character sequence in either tr or sed

Tags: sed, tr

Have a file that has been created incorrectly. There are several space delimited fields in the file but one text field has some unwanted newlines. This is causing a big problem.

How can I remove these characters but not the wanted line ends?

file is:

```
'Number field' 'Text field'                    'Number field'
   1            Some text                       999999
   2            more
text                             111111111
   3            Even more text                  8888888888
EOF
```

So there is a NL after the word "more".

I've tried sed:

```
sed 's/.$//g' test.txt > test.out
```

and

```
sed 's/\n//g' test.txt > test.out
```

But none of these work. The newlines do not get removed.

`tr -d '\n'` does too much - I need to remove ONLY the newlines that are preceded by a space.

How can I delete newlines that follow a space?

SunOS  5.10 Generic_144488-09 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440

Comment: better to try and fix that at the source, or at least in the process that extracts it from the source. `tr` won't help here. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like an XY-problem. Instead of programming some artificial intelligence recognizing good and bad newlines, fix the artificial stupidity creating the broken fields.

Comment: Yes the fix is the next task. Thanks for the help

Comment: Inconsistent whether you have CRs or LFs in your file - I've edited assuming the latter.  Please post an unambiguous representation of the broken line (hexdump, backslash escapes, whatever).

Answer (score 2):

A sed solution is

```
sed '/ $/{N;s/\n//}'
```

Explanation:

- `/ $/`: whenever the line ends in space, then
- `N`: append a newline and the next line of input, and
- `s/\n//`: delete the newline.

Comment: WARNING: the given sed command will not join more than two lines together at a time.  For example: `sed '/ $/{N;s/\n//;}' <<< $'a \nb \nc \n'` will produce two lines, whereas perhaps the goal is to produce just one. (The original problem description does say "one text field has some unwanted newlines" (plural).)

Comment: Good morning,There is only one new line added as far as I can see so far. The file has been extracted from the database with user CRs. I also have to fix the issue of stripping out the these CRs in the extract. That should be straight forward as it's PL/SQL. I know how to to do this.

Comment: @peak - quite right - you need a loop like `:;/ $/{N;s/\n//;b}` to deal with a succession of lines ending in space.

Comment: `:;/ $/{N;s/\n//;b}` works nicely with gnu-sed but amazingly not with e.g. Mac OS X mavericks sed.

Comment: BSD sed is a bit more picky about syntax - it's often easier to provide the command as a script for sed.  You need something like (untested) `sed -e ':loop' -e '/ $/{' -e 'N' -e 's/\n//' -e 'bloop' -e '}'` to be properly portable.  My Perl answer is much more comfortable...!

Answer (score 1):

It might be simplest with Perl:

```
perl -p0 -e 's/ \n/ /g'
```

The `-0` flag makes Perl read the entire file as one line.  Then we can substitute using `s` in the usual way.  You can, of course, also add the `-i` option to edit the file in-place.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I delete newlines that follow a space?

If you want every occurrence of `$' \n'` in the original file to be replaced by a space (`$' '`), and if you know of a character (e.g. a control character) that does not appear in the file, then the task can be accomplished quite simply using sed and tr (as you requested).  Let's suppose, for example, that control-A is a character that is not in the file.  For the sake of simplicity, let's also assume we can use bash.  Then the following script should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$'\01'
tr '\n' "$A" | sed "s/ $A/ /g" | tr "$A" '\n'
```